# Split items into several groups evenly

Tags: php, algorithm

I have the following problem to which I'm trying to implement a solution in PHP.
I have a certain amount of items that I want to evenly split among groups of certain amounts.
The final result would be an almost evenly numbers of groups of a certain amount

**EXAMPLE**

**Items to distribute**: 199950

**Groups**:

- Group #1 : 50 items
- Group #2 : 100 items
- Group #3 : 250 items
- Group #4 : 500 items
- Group #5 : 1000 items

**Result**:

- 107 x Group #1
- 106 x Group #2
- 106 x Group #3
- 105 x Group #4
- 105 x Group #5

Comment: Where are your items stored?  Please can you share what you've tried?

Comment: It's quite simple to achieve, did you try anything on your side then show us so we can help furthermore ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet...
The items to distribute is just a number stored in a variable and the idea is to create an array for the groups, storing in each element the result of the calculation for each group

Comment: So if the size of each type of group is a, b, c, d, e, and you have the same number n of each group type, the total t = n x a + n x b + n x c + n x d + n x e, which you can simplify to t = n (a + b + c + d + e).  Rearrange a little, and use PHP syntax and `floor()` to round down to the neareset whole number, gives you `$n = floor($total / array_sum($groups))`.  Start with the biggest sized group and repeat to get your desired result

Comment: Thanks @RobEyre, that pointed me to a possible successful outcome :)
I'm going to try and implement a solution now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (assuming `$groups` are in increasing sizes):

```php
function splitItems($groups, $items)
{
    $n = count($groups);
    $res = array_fill(0, $n, 0);

    while($items >= $groups[0])
    {
        for($i=$n-1;$i>=0;$i--)
        {
            if($items >= $groups[$i])
            {
                $res[$i]++;
                $items -= $groups[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    if($items > 0)
        $res[0]++;
    return $res;
}

$res = splitItems([50, 100, 250, 500, 1000], 199950);
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 107
    [1] => 106
    [2] => 106
    [3] => 105
    [4] => 105
)
```